# MySQL/Hibernate Inconsistent Data Structures

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to build a 4-tier Web-Application in Java. I'm using the Hibernate Framework for ORM and a MySQL Database. 
The table "project" has a one-to-many relation to the table "idea". What I'm trying to do, is to get a List (or Set) of Ideas using the following function:

```
public static List getProjectIdeas(int projectId)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from Idea where id_project=" + projectId);
        List<Idea> ideaList = (List<Idea>) q.list();
        System.out.println(ideaList.size());
        return ideaList;
    }
```

At first, it works fine and I get all the ideas from the database. But when I add new ideas to the project and then call the function again, I don't always get a complete list of the ideas related to the project back. The size of the list I receive from q.list() varies between the number of ideas stored in the database before the insert and the actual number of ideas.
This is the function I use to insert the Idea into the Database:

```
public static void writeObject(Object object)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(object);
        tx.commit();
    }
```

This is my first hibernate project, so i don't know if there is anything wrong with the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">***/ideator</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <mapping resource="mapping/Category.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mapping/Rating.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mapping/Idea.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mapping/Participation.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mapping/Project.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mapping/Criteria.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mapping/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix the bug. Apparently, it was not a good idea to use getCurrentSession. Better manage the session by yourself:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       Transaction tx = null;
       Idea idea = null;

       try {
           tx = session.beginTransaction();
           idea = (Idea) session.get(Idea.class, id);
           tx.commit();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           if(tx != null) {
               tx.rollback();
           }
       } finally {
           session.flush();
       }

       return idea;
```

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, hibernate is cool. Once you get it working, things are really nice and easy with hibernate. But there are starting up issues. So you are on the right track. The code sample above is really nice. Its a good question. Welcome to stackoverflow.

This is what I do and it works for me.

Constructor

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure() ;                     
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder() .buildServiceRegistry());
```

When flushing to database

```
public void flush(Object dataStore) throws DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError {
    Transaction txD;
    Session session;
    session = currentSession();
    txD = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(dataStore);
    try {
        txD.commit();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        log.error("Unable to store data from "+dataStore.getClass().toString()) ;
        throw new DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError(dataStore);
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        log.debug("txD state isActive" + txD.isActive() + " txD is participating" + txD.isParticipating());
        log.debug(e);
    }  finally {
        txD = null;
        session.close();
    }
}
```

CurrentSession method

```
public final ThreadLocal    session = new ThreadLocal();
public Session currentSession() {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this thread has none yet
    if (s == null || !s.isOpen()) {
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        // Store it in the ThreadLocal variable
        session.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but I'm not quiet sure where to implement these functions, because instead of your currentSession i use HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(). I don't use flush at all, i think hibernate does it automatically.

Comment: I do not use Hibernate Util. And the flush is my own implementation. Hibernate does not have a flush, it has a commit.